# pooling with Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, pooling

I've tried out the pooling lifestyle with Windsor.
Lets say I want multiple CustomerTasks to work with a pool of ILogger's.
when i try resolving more times than maxPoolSize, new loggers keeps getting created.

what am I missing and what exactly is the meaning of max pool size?

the xml configuration i use is (demo code):

```
<component id="customertasks" type="WindsorTest.CustomerTasks, WindsorTestCheck" lifestyle="transient" />
<component id="logger.console" service="WindsorTest.ILogger, WindsorTestCheck" type="WindsorTest.ConsoleLogger, WindsorTestCheck" lifestyle="pooled" initialPoolSize="2" maxPoolSize="5" />
```

Code is:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message);
}

public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
{
    private static int count = 0;
    public ConsoleLogger()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from constructor number:" + count);
        count++;
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

public class CustomerTasks
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public CustomerTasks(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    public void SaveCustomer()
    {
        logger.Log("Saved customer");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/InversionOfControlAndDependencyInjectionWithCastleWindsorContainerPart4.aspx) article in dotnetslackers that pretty much cleared things up for me.
**maxPoolSize** is the maximal number of instances that will be returned to the pool upon release. subsequent releases will result in objects being discarded.

one inaccuracy i've noticed is that **initialPoolSize** is the number of instances created upon first resolve and **NOT** container creation like the article claims (probably due to version changes since it was written)